# Vue watch() outputs same oldValue and newValue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When doing my frontend Vue project, I have the need of executing certain steps when element(s) are pushed into the list in `data`. However, when I pushed some initial values into the list in `mounted()`, the `console.log()` in the corresponding `watch()` outputs the same value for the `newVal` and `oldVal` parameter values.

Javascript/Vue code:

```js
let app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        testList: [],
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.testList.push('a');
        this.testList.push('b');
        this.testList.push('c');
    },
    watch: {
        testList: {
            handler: function(newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log("new", newVal);
                console.log("old", oldVal);
            },
        },
    }
});
```

The console logging information:
[image: Console logging information]

1. Why do the `newVal` and `oldVal` hold the same value?
2. Why isn't the `watch()` function being executed three times (since I pushed three times in `mounted()`)?

Comment: Any luck if you add `immediate: true` to the watch function? So it will look like `testList: { handler (...), immediate: true }`

Comment: I tried using ```immediate: true``` but nothing happened. Finally I defined the function in handler in ```methods```, mapped the handler of ```testList``` to the function in ```methods```, and exectue manually the new method I defined and it worked. But this is not elegant 

Answer (score 10):

In addition, if someone is having this problem when watching nested properties changes, and using flag **deep: true**, it's expected that newValue and oldValue are the same ([reference](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers)).

To overcome the issue, you could add computed property wrapping the data object that should be watched, and watch for changes on the computed property instead.

```
export default {
name: 'ExampleComponent',
data () {
    return {
        exampleObject: {
            name: 'User',
            email: 'Email'
        }
    }
},

computed: {
    computedObjectToBeWatched () {
        return Object.assign({}, this.exampleObject)
    }
},

watch: {
    computedObjectToBeWatched: {
        deep: true,
        handler (value, oldValue) {
            if (value.name !== oldValue.name) {
                console.log('changes occured')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And to get aquainted with this solution in the Vue 3 / Composition API syntax.

`const usedToBeWatched = ref([]);`

`const watchedComputed = computed(() => structuredClone(toRaw(usedToBeWatched.value)));`

`watch(watchedComputed, (newVal, oldVal) => { console.log('watchedComputed', newVal, oldVal) }));`

Answer (score 9):

I have changed two thing

1. do clone in watch
2. added computed

It works fine now.

```js
console.clear();

let app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        testList: ['old'],
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.testList.push('a');
        this.testList.push('b');
        this.testList.push('c');
    },
    watch: {
        testListClone: { //<-- Edited
            handler: function(newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log("new", newVal);
                console.log("old", oldVal);
            },
        },
    },
  computed:{  //<-- Added
    clonedItems: function(){
       return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.testList))
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Cool! This works. However I believe there is a typo in this answer: in ```computed``` the variable is called ```clonedItems```, but in ```watch``` it is called ```testListClone```. Only when these two names are the same, the code could work. Can you change the typo and fix the indentation problem in ```computed``` so that I can mark this as the answer? Thx

Comment: Also, in this case, I found that ```watch``` is only executed one time. Why isn't it executed 3 times?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no answer as to why it returns the same value, I will say that your Array (or Object) is a reference, so both `oldValue` and `newValue` refer to the same reference.

No different than in pure JavaScript:

```
const oldArr = [{ name: 'jim' }];
const newArr = oldArr;
newArr[0].name = 'susan';
console.log({ oldArr, newArr });
// { oldArr: [ { name: 'susan' } ], newArr: [ { name: 'susan' } ] }
```

In order to make `oldValue` and `newValue` work as expected, you need to watch a primitive such as a String or Number.

You could do something hacky such as:

```
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
// cloneDeep is used to deep-copy to avoid copying references
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash.clonedeep';

const newArr = ref([]);
const oldArr = ref([]);

watch(() => newArr.value, () => {
    console.log('old value', oldArr.value);
    console.log('new value', newArr.value);

    // last step
    oldArr.value = cloneDeep(newArr.value);
}, { deep: true });
```